# How to show plugin output in wordpress frontend

Tags: wordpress, plugins, frontend

I have developed a plugin in Wordpress having admin and frontpage part. Admin part is ready. Now I need to show plugin content in frontend.

How can I do it?

I have seen many pages that Google suggested, but none has helped.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated,

Jaime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure that your code is registering the widget to WordPress
2. Activate your plugin from the WordPress Admin area > Plugins
3. Go to WordPress Admin area > Appearance > Widget, you should see
   your new widget listed there
4. Drag your widget onto a sidebar and save your changes
5. View the wigdet on the side bar of your WordPress front end

Comment: using this same question...I could add the plugin HTML to the sidebar.... but how can I do it in the menu? currently, there is a menu showing all pages with "?page_id=xx" and so on. Is it possible to add the widget content among the other menu links?

Comment: @jstuardo Its better to post this as a new question that will help you to get attention from more SO users.

Comment: Kindly help me that how you done it, as I want the same functionality with JS-Composer